# CiviPledge custom styling

Tags: css, civipledge

In which file can I find and edit CiviPledge CSS styling to make the form look more in line with the rest of my site? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's best to not edit the files directly, but to create your own file. Otherwise it will get overwritten with each upgrade you do. In the version I'm using, I can set the custom CSS file here:

/civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1

I use the "inspect" option in Chrome to see what CSS is being applied, then I copy it into my custom css file, and edit it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jenni Simonis's answer about creating a global custom civicrm CSS file, I restyled our contribution pages and explained the process in [this answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27721/styling-contribution-pages-with-buttons/27722#27722). I'm sure something similar could apply to pledges with your own styles. My purpose for using a separate CSS file (rather than my global custom civi css) for contributions was to have more control over which price sets it applied to.