# How to customize the layout of a Contribution form created in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

The title pretty much describes the question. In Wordpress it is easy to customize the layout of a post/page by using child theme. I wonder how to do so for a CiviComponent, say, contribution page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup a custom template directory (Administer > System Settings > Directories > Custom Template Directory) and add code to a Main.extra.tpl (the directory is (your_path/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.extra.tpl) and also see this [Styling Contribution pages with buttons](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27721/styling-contribution-pages-with-buttons/27722#comment38111_27722).

Or use an extension which is a preferred way: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/templates/customizing/.

You can also add a custom style sheet for civi under Administer > System Settings > Resource URL's > Custom CSS URL for global styling changes. Conversely, if you want your theme to handle styling then configure 
[CiviCRM Admin Utilities](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-admin-utilities/) which will give you an option on disabling civicrm.css on the front-end.

[image]